# What is the difference in using CStringW/CStringA and CT2W/CT2A to convert strings?

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, unicode, mfc

In the past, I used `CT2W` and `CT2A` to convert string between Unicode & Ansi. Now It seems that `CStringW` and `CStringA` can also do the same task.

I write the following code snippet:

```
CString str = _T("Abc");
CStringW str1;
CStringA str2;
CT2W str3(str);
CT2A str4(str);

str1 = str;
str2 = str;
```

It seems `CStringW` and `CStringA` also perform conversions by using `WideCharToMultibyte` when I assign `str` to them.

So, what is the advantages of using `CT2W`/`CT2A` instead of `CStringW`/`CStringA`, since I have never heard of the latter pair. Neither MS recommend the latter pair to do the conversion.

Answer (score 8):

`CString` offers a number of [conversion constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class#cstringt) to convert between ANSI and Unicode encoding. They are as convenient as they are dangerous, often masking bugs. MFC allows you to disable implicit conversion by defining the `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` preprocessor symbol (which you probably should). Conversions always involve creating of a new `CString` object with heap-allocated storage (ignoring the short string optimization).

By contrast, the `Cs2d` macros (where `s` = source, `d` = destination) work on raw C-style strings; no `CString` instances are created in the process of converting between character encodings. A temporary buffer of 128 code units is always allocated on the stack, in addition to a heap-allocated buffer in case the conversion requires more space.

Both of the above perform a conversion with an implied ANSI codepage (either `CP_THREAD_ACP` or `CP_ACP` in case the `_CONVERSION_DONT_USE_THREAD_LOCALE` preprocessor symbol is defined). `CP_ACP` is particularly troublesome, as it's a process-global setting, that any thread can change at any time.

Which one should you choose for your conversions? Neither of the above. Use the `EX` versions instead (see [string and text classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/string-and-text-classes) for a full list). Those are implemented as class templates that give you a lot more control you need to reliably perform your conversions. The template non-type parameter lets you control the static buffer. More importantly, those class templates have constructors with an explicit codepage parameter, so you can perform the conversion you want (including from and to UTF-8), and document your intent in code.

Comment: Well explained. I wasn't aware of this EX versions. Question, for C++ only projects, is this the recommended way too?

Comment: @tom: The conversion macros/class templates seem to have dependencies on MFC or ATL, so they cannot easily be used in non-MFC/ATL code. For a pure C++ project I would have suggested [std::codecvt](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt), but those are being deprecated, with no replacement. [std::mbtowc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbtowc) is another alternative, but it depends on the current locale, that cannot be set per thread. With no satisfactory option available, I would probably recommend to just write your own conversion infrastructure.

Comment: CW2A is a typedef for CW2AEX.  There is no need to use the EX version explicitly, then, right?

Comment: @dan `CW2A` is an alias for a *specific* `CW2AEX` class template instantiation. I believe the `CW2AEX` class template is parameterized on the initial buffer size allocated for the output buffer. Thus, they are functionally equivalent, with potentially different performance characteristics. Whether you use `CW2A` or `CW2AEX` then depends on how good a fit the default of 128 code units is for your specific case. Though I seem to recall that the `EX` variants used to provide a richer API, allowing you to pass in the specific code page you wanted to use. I could be wrong.

Comment: in `atlconv.h`, it simply declares `typedef CW2AEX<> CW2A;`  Doesn't this mean you basically can use them interchangeably, albeit with parens for the shorter `CW2A`?

Comment: @dan They are still very different. `CW2AEX` is a class template, `CW2A` is a class template instantiation. In other words: `CW2AEX<42>` is valid, whereas `CW2A<42>` is not.

Comment: Ah, I see, it's actually an empty initializer that's been typedefed?

Comment: @dan Syntactically, that's correct. Semantically, the empty template argument list picks up the defaults. `CW2AEX` is parameterized on a single non-type template argument that defaults to 128. `CW2A` is thus a type alias for `CW2AEX<128>`. None of this is of much practical value, though, unless you are a library author, or your profiler identified [`WideCharToMultiByte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte) as a potential bottleneck.

Comment: Thanks for indulging me.  Would it be fair, then, to say that `CW2A(str, CP_UTF8)` (or whatever codepage) is most likely the right choice, and it's not strictly true, in your last paragraph above, that you should "use the EX" versions, unless you consider that CW2A *is* really an EX version?

Comment: "CP_ACP is particularly troublesome, as it's a process-global setting, that any thread can change at any time" - WRONG. CP_ACP represents the system Ansi codepage. You cannot change that on a per-process or per-thread basis. It is a system-wide setting.