# Which code page is used for the implicit conversion of CStringA to CStringW?

Tags: c++, mfc, atl

I'm asking this more out of curiosity.

Considering this code snippet:

```
CStringA narrow;
CStringW wide;
...
wide = narrow; // which code page is used for the conversion 
               // of the narrow string to wide string?
```

Which code page is used for the conversion of the `CStringA` string to `CStringW`? It appears to use the `CP_ACP` code page, but is this guaranteed?

Instead of `wide = narrow;` I'm actually using `wide = CA2W(narrow, CP_ACP);`, so I can specify explicitly the desired code page.

Disclaimer: I know that wide strings should be used all over the place, but this is used for a MBCS legacy software.

Comment: I would have expected it to use CP_THREAD_ACP rather than CP_ACP (though most of the time they should be the same).

Comment: Several years ago, Microsoft started recommending that UTF-8 string should be used all over the place, and in preference over the W routines.  But that isn't applicable to legacy software (unless "converting from MBCS to UTF-8 for this legacy software" is something worth tackling).  (I don't have the link handy, I had read it here on SO from a post from @phuclv who has posted about these issues many times.)

Comment: @Eljay *"Several years ago, Microsoft started recommending that UTF-8 string should be used all over the place, and in preference over the W routines."* - Microsoft **never** communicated this recommendation. This is completely made up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ATL is open source. ATL `StringT` uses `_AtlGetConversionACP()`:

```
inline UINT WINAPI _AtlGetConversionACP() throw()
{
#ifdef _CONVERSION_DONT_USE_THREAD_LOCALE
    return CP_ACP;
#else
    return CP_THREAD_ACP;
#endif
}
```

Comment: I just managed to track it down to this function too, but thanks anyway. This seems to be more or less a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59404120/what-is-the-difference-in-using-cstringw-cstringa-and-ct2w-ct2a-to-convert-strin